# Server-Side Synchronization not syncing tasks, appointments and contacts to CRM from Outlook Web App

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, server-side-sync

I have enabled Server-Side synchronization for Incoming mail, outgoing mail and Appointments, Tasks and Contacts on mailboxes in Dynamics CRM 2013. 
The mailboxes have been approved and enabled and also statuses for all 3 modes are successful.

However,
Contacts, Tasks and Appointments created in CRM are synced properly in the Office 365 web application. But not the other way round. What must have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When properly configured, any task/appointment/contact created in CRM will be synced to the user’s Exchange mailbox. Once synced with Exchange, those same items can then be edited directly in the Exchange side (Outlook), and changes will reflect back in CRM. It will not sync a Task, Appointment, or Contact created directly from Exchange, since the majority of them are personal and do not need to be in CRM.
http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/server-side-sync/advantages/

Comment: And what about emails sent from an outlook to a CRM user? Do mails appear in the CRM which are sent by Outlook? Because I can't see a mail appear in my CRM. Statuses are showing Success for all.

Comment: Though I did receive a mail which was a reply to my sent mail from CRM, but not received new created mail. Is it how it is supposed to be ?

Answer (score -1):

Give Full Read Access To "Email Server Profile" On "Business Management" to the user Role